# Payload body of a HTTP GET request

Tags: rest, api

https://www.absolute.com/-/media/Commercial/resources/api/abt-api-working-with-absolute.pdf?la=en

I am trying to make the canonical request part for this one. On page 6 there is this part: Encoded hash of payload: Hash the entire body, HexEncode, and apply lowercase . I am not sure what is the payload that I should work on here if I'm trying to do a GET request. Is it the GET/POST params, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3):

Payload is some data you send on the body of POST requests.
You can see more information [on the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

With [Postman examples](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/) you can see some requests, and notice POST is the only one which has `body`.

Comment: The link with examples is not valid anymore.

Comment: @mfudi Thanks, I've uploaded the link.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, @Felipe is slightly wrong here. Mistook what OP meant by payload. Generally payload does mean Body, but with Absolutes REST API, you send the payload in the Authorization header. It is a standard. And there is way better documentation available in AWS than Absolute.

Absolute also have C# SDKs.

[AbsoluteSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AbsolutePublicAPI/)

[AWS Signature Version 4 Docs or Signing a Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)