# Send http get with request body c#

Tags: c#, get, dotnet-httpclient

I want to send an HTTP GET with a request body.  I know there is much heated debate about whether this should ever be done or not but I am not interested in debating it I simply want to do it. I'm using C# and ASP.NET and my code is below.  Unfortunately it throws an exception "Cannot send a content-body with this verb type".  Please, any help on how to get this done will be very appreciated!

```
// Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
            var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memRequest);

            // Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
            var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = u,
                    Content = httpContent
                };

                var result = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseBody = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you can't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Payload body of a HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250018/payload-body-of-a-http-get-request). what debate are you referring to? GET never had a "request body" specified. related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589852/1132334

Comment: I think your issue is that the .NET team did debate it and decided that GET requests shouldn't have bodies.  Since the rest of the world is able to get by with this restriction, you might want to rethink your approach.

Comment: @dlatikay thanks for sending but that is specific to postman, I'm working with C# and ASP.NET

Comment: Apparently this can be done in .NET Core https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902348/62600

Comment: Thank you @ToddMenier.  This is helpful and has lots of interesting additional information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible for HttpClient to send content or body for GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421126/possible-for-httpclient-to-send-content-or-body-for-get-request)